# C# Linq class searching - how to filter object collection

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to ask how to filter a particular class in an object collection using Linq?

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
List<object> c = new List<object>();
c.Add(c1);
c.Add(c1);
c.Add(c2);
```

I am searching for something like this:

```
c.Select();
// or
IEnumerable<object> x = from y in c;
```

Appreciate your response. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OfType<T>` for this.

```
var results = c.OfType<Class1>();
```

This

```
Console.WriteLine (c.OfType<Class1>().Count());
```

results in

> 2

As a sidenote: `.Select()` doesn't select anything. Well, in a way it does: it "selects" each element and projects it to a new object. But it doesn't select objects on some criterium. For values, there is `.Where()` and likewise selectors and `.OfType<T>` for the type selection.

Answer (score 3):

```
c.OfType<Class1>() // returns an IEnumerable<Class1> with all instances of Class1 within C
c.OfType<Class2>() // same thing, but for Class2
```

Using the `OfType<T>` method, you can then use the remainder of the LINQ query filters on the strongly typed IEnumerable.